# onClick listener delegation on UI Button

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, listener, unityscript, delegation

So since 4.6 unity uses a new UI system, what i never used. Until now.

What I'm trying to do is generating buttons in a dynamic way, thus I also have to add the onClick event in a dynamic way (or atleast through scripting).

I've tryed to extend the onClick Listener, but it doesn't want to work:

```
btn.GetComponent<Button>().onClick.AddListener(() => { placeBuilding(obj.name); });
```

It will give this error which does sounds pretty clear in what is wrong:

`Assets/Scripts/Menu/btnBouwen.cs(72,45): error CS0119: Expression denotes a 'method group', where a 'variable', 'value' or 'type' was expected`

However I have no idea how to use an `UnityAction` as it seems the required type for the call.

Feels like I'm missing something really easy. Hope somebody can help me.

Kind regards,
Nkmol

Comment: Umm, why do you want to add on Click Listener to the new UI? I am just curious cause it already have a onClick listener, that response perfectly to a Mouse Click and to Touches, Multiple Touches aswell. Unlike OnGui you don't have to add Listner, or IF condition at the beginning. 

You can even make a public method to any script and open the ButtonObject OnClick component, and drag the gameobject with the public method on it, and select the method in the drop down so it will fire it.

Comment: Do you mean at some point, that you want to drag an GameObject to the onClick of the new UI and try to access the scripts from there? I understand that you want to do this dynamically and I am curious because I have never done it as well.

Comment: @Aizen Imagine you have a `List<>` with certain values which can have more values once the application is running. With this i loop through this list and for each value i want to generate a `Button`. This is all generated by code and thus i cannot use the GUI of unity and dragging the GameObject to the onClick event.

Comment: I understand. Let me try it myself and see if I can pull this off. I might use this procedure in the future as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem i was facing is that my `Button` was conflicting with a custom class i made called `Button.cs`. Now i've learned not to use Class names that already exist in the environment^^

fixed it with the direct path to the Class:

```
UnityEngine.UI.Button btn = newButton.GetComponent<UnityEngine.UI.Button>();
btn.onClick.RemoveAllListeners(); 
btn.onClick.AddListener(() => placeBuilding(obj.name));
```

**code:**

```
GameObject button = Resources.Load <GameObject>("Button"); //loading from resource

GameObject newButton = Instantiate(button);
newButton.transform.parent = panel.transform;
newButton.GetComponentInChildren<Text>().text = obj.name;
newButton.transform.position = button.transform.position;
newButton.transform.position += new Vector3(20*x, -70 * z, 0);
UnityEngine.UI.Button btn = newButton.GetComponent<UnityEngine.UI.Button>();
btn.onClick.RemoveAllListeners(); 
btn.onClick.AddListener(() => placeBuilding(obj.name));
```

This code is inside a loop

Comment: Up. Cool, any downside on this approach? where did the newButton came from? Did you ref a new Button type then GetComponent? After that ref another btn with the namespace added then assign the newButton? 

So you need to at lease make 2 declaration for this to work right?

Comment: I just made a prefab of a button, loaded it from the Resources, instantiated it and added needed configuration. Added code on update.

Answer (score 3):

Well I got something working, that might suits your needs.

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
using UnityEngine.UI;
using UnityEngine.EventSystems;

public class MainLab : MonoBehaviour, IPointerClickHandler {

// Use this for initialization




    void Start () {

}



    public void OnPointerClick(PointerEventData eventData)
    {

        Debug.Log("Hello");
    }
}
```

In this we added, UnityEngine.EventSystems and then added the Interface IpointerClickHandler. FYI you can also add Drag or whatever interface you may want.

then just and the the method interface. RightClick the IPinterClickHandler then choose Implement Interface to check what other method it has.

You would need to attach this to a gameObject. ANY GameObject. Including buttons.

So Dynamically in your List of Buttons, either you want to add this as a component. AddComponent();   I call my class MainLab for testing purposes.

Comment: Thanks for your comment, even though it would work for my example it is not as dynamic as i want it to. It requires a new class and with different methods in the future for the onClick event, this would require to add different PointerClasses on every different button.

Answer (score 0):

How about passing the Lambda as a delegate?

```
btn.GetComponent<Button>().onClick.AddListener(delegate
{
    () => { placeBuilding(obj.name); }
});
```

Comment: The lambda is already used as a anonymous method, it is the same as using a delegate but shorter in this case.

Answer (score 0):

The following line should work fine.

```
btn.GetComponent<Button>().onClick.AddListener(() => { });
```

The problem is in `placeBuilding(obj.name);`, make sure it works outside of lambda. Consult with [this page](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b0kht3zf.aspx).